# how to check a value of a key is true in postgres jsonb query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, boolean

For example my table is :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    foo jsonb
);
```

and it has some values :

```
id   | foo
-----+-------
 1   | "{'a':false,'b':true}"
 2   | "{'a':true,'b':false}"
 3   | NULL
```

I want to know how to check if value of a key is `true` , and which **operator** should I use?

I want something like this that can check the value :

```
SELECT 1 
FROM mytable
WHERE
id=2
AND
foo['a'] is true
;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax `foo['a']` is invalid in Postgres.

If you want to access the value of a key, you need to use the `->>` operator [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
select *
from mytable
where id = 2
and foo ->> 'a' = 'true';
```

Comment: Note that this will not distinguish between boolean `true` and string `"true"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 1
FROM mytable
Where
id=2
AND
(foo ->> 'a')::boolean is true;
;
```

Answer (score 2):

More correct might be

```
SELECT 1
  FROM mytable
 WHERE id=2
   AND (foo -> 'a') = 'true'::JSONB;
```

This has the benefit of allowing postgres to make better use of any indexes you may have on your jsonB data as well as avoiding some of the ambiguity with the `->>` operator that others have mentioned.

Using `->>`

```
=> SELECT (('{"a": true}'::JSONB)->>'a') = 'true' as result;
 result 
--------
 t
(1 row)

=> SELECT (('{"a": "true"}'::JSONB)->>'a') = 'true' as result;
 result 
--------
 t
(1 row)
```

Using `->`

```
=> SELECT (('{"a": "true"}'::JSONB)->'a') = 'true'::JSONB as result;
 result 
--------
 f
(1 row)

=> SELECT (('{"a": true}'::JSONB)->'a') = 'true'::JSONB as result;
 result 
--------
 t
(1 row)
```

Note: This is the same as Tamlyn's answer, but with an included example of how to compare against a JSONB `true`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `text` value of a key use `->>` (double head) and to get the `json` or `jsonb` value use `->` (single head).

Be careful because the `text` representations of JSON boolean value `true` and string value `"true"` are both `true`.

```
tamlyn=# select '{"a":true}'::json->>'a' bool, '{"a":"true"}'::json->>'a' str;
 bool | str
------+------
 true | true
(1 row)
```

In your case you probably want `->`.

```
tamlyn=# select '{"a":true}'::json->'a' bool, '{"a":"true"}'::json->'a' str;
 bool |  str
------+--------
 true | "true"
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the JSON object field, cast to boolean and do a regular SQL where clause:

```sql
select * 
from mytable
where (foo -> 'a')::boolean is true;
```